# Which site is suitable for asking questions regarding Lenovo tablets

Tags: support, scope, questions, question-appropriateness

We do have a tag on Android.SE for [tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablet).

Are questions regarding Lenovo tablets suitable on Android.SE, or on any other Stack Exchange Network site?

I want to ask something regarding my tab getting hold frequently.

Comment: So long as you don't ask us how to repair the hardware or how to load a non-Android OS on it, we would take questions for tablets (irrespective of the vendor) on which Android runs. It is better if you edit and add your actual question so that we can advise suitably.

Comment: @Firelord edited

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the OS and the nature of the question.**

As far as I know, Lenovo tablets are packaged with either Android, Windows, or Chrome OS.

To put it simply:

- If it's about doing something about the Android OS, then it's mostly on-topic here.
- Else, if it's about operating Windows, installing *nix-based OS, etc., then it's highly possibly off-topic (try other sister sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), etc.)

Comment: If it is about like my tab gets hold frequently and I want to ask about it then on which platform it would suit?

Comment: @JitendraSingh Sorry, I'm not familiar with the term "gets hold frequently", could you edit and provide an example of the complete question on this meta's question?

Comment: whenever i switch on the wifi in my tab and open apps the apps get stuck and do not respond. Even I am not able to go to home screen forcefully I have to switch off the wifi and then the tablet gets okay. How to make it such that my tablet doesn't gets stuck when wifi is turned on is my question